# What will be the issues upgrading from Solr 3.6.0 to 4.x or 5.x?

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I’ve inherited a project that uses a Solr 3.6.0 deployment.   (Several
masters and several slaves – I think there are 6 Solr instances in total.)

I’ve been tasked with investigating if upgrading our 3.6.0 deployment will improve performance – there’s a lot of data and things are getting slow, apparently.

I’ve read Apache docs that from 3.6.x to 4.x there were improvements in scalability and performance.

I see that from 4.x to 5.x that Solr is now a standable server and no longer just a WAR running on Tomcat.

ISSUES:

A. Is it worth upgrading to 4.x or 5.x?  Will I see a big improvement in performance?

B. Should I got to 4.x or 5.x?  Will 4.x be an easier upgrade path since it's just a new WAR file?

C. In a nutshell ... what will the upgrade path look like, what kind of steps am I in for, and how can I avoid trouble?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

**It depends.**

If stuff runs fine today and you don't need the extra performance or functionality - there is no good reason to touch it. You're so far behind that upgrading will be a large thing anyway. If you need the performance or the functionality, yes. It's worth it. You'll see an increase in performance and you can use a more recent Java version (current trunk of Lucene requires Java8).

If you can't reindex easily, you'll have to go through 4.x to get to 5.x anyway, since the current version of 5.x might not be able to read your current index format. If you can reindex easily, go directly to 5.x. You'll have to deal with the change in how Solr is being run at some time, better do it now when you're doing the breaking upgrade anyways.

Have a backup, replicate the current environment to a experimental server and try the update there. If you can easily reindex, set up 5.x and index to it and see if you can run the application straight from that backend instead (in development, not production). If it works (and you can reindex easily), create a Solr 5.x instance to run in parallel to your current installation, reindex to that and switch over production after confirming that it works in dev.

If you can't reindex, create a development clone of the current core and try to find the upgrade path that is able to upgrade the index files as you're going along. You're going to have to read a bit of documentation and try out different versions to get a proper migration of the index file format going.